# how to change particular column value on cascade

Tags: java, sql-server

I have three tables

```
Company
Department
Cost-centers
```

and they have a one-to-many relationship. like my company may have multiple departments. in my company, there is a column `is_active`.

If I change that column from active to inactive than the associated department with that particular company should be inactive(not deleted) and cost centers associated with that particular dept should also change to inactive.

I'm using cascade delete but I don't want to delete I just want to update that particular column from active to inactive.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create an UPDATE trigger for the Company table, something like this:

```
if update(is_Active) begin
   update Department set is_Active=i.is_Active
      from Department as d inner join inserted as i
      on d.CompanyID = i.ID
      where d.CompanyID = i.ID and d.is_Active<>i.is_Active
end
```

And another trigger in Department, in the same way, that updates the Cost_Centers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a trigger for such things like below

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.objects  
      WHERE name = 'updateOtherColumns' AND type = 'TR')  
   DROP TRIGGER updateOtherColumns;  
GO  
CREATE TRIGGER updateOtherColumns
ON Company 
AFTER UPDATE   
AS
IF UPDATE(is_active)
BEGIN
    UPDATE D
    SET    D.is_active= C.is_active
    FROM  Departments D INNER JOIN Company C 
    ON D.id=C.dept_id and D.is_active <>C.is_active
    --first update departments and then cost-centers
    UPDATE CC
    SET    CC.is_active= D.is_active
    FROM  Departments D INNER JOIN Cost_Centers CC 
    ON D.cost_center_id=CC.id and D.is_active <>CC.is_active
END

GO
```